# Re module not working for computer science coursework

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

So I am trying to use the re module to see if a number plate matches with how a number plate should be, but I keep getting errors with the module, my code is below.

```
def nplatec():
    import re
    r_plate = "^[Aa-Zz]{2}[0-9][Aa-Zz]{3}$"
    while True:
        u_plate = input("Enter your number plate WITHOUT spaces please : ")
        a_speed = int(input("Enter you average speed : "))
        s_limit = 70
        if re.match(r_plate, u_plate):
            print("InCorrect number plate")
            break
nplatec()
```

Errors:

[image: error]

Comment: Please edit and use formatting to provide a readable question.

Comment: Add errors as text not a link to an image.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, its meant to be `"^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9][A-Za-z]{3}$"` rather than `"^[Aa-Zz]{2}[0-9][Aa-Zz]{3}$"`